# Values of a promise in JS within for loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, javascript-objects, es6-promise

I am lost in the *promised* land and could really use some guidance. I have exhausted searching numerous SO questions (2-3 hours of reading solutions + docs) related to this seemingly common issue and feel I just am not getting it.

### Overview

Below I have code that takes in an Object type (`resources`), grabs a few values from this Object and then calculates distance and duration from the GoogleMaps Distance Matrix. The results of the function `googleRequest()` are a promise containing two values (distance and duration).

I would like to get these two values back within the for loop, execute `pushToRows()`, and then return an array called `final_rows`.

### Problem

`final_rows` shows UNDEFINED for the duration and distance keys within each row. I speculate this is occurring because I am attempting to access the values in `dist_dur` inappropriately. I would appreciate any help on resolving this issue. Thanks.

### Code

```
final_rows = []

    function getDistTime(resources){
        for (var i = 0; i < resources.data.length; i++) {
            var origin1 = $("#citystate").val();
            var destinationA = resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION CITY'] + ',' + resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION STATE'];
            var dist_time_data = googleRequest(origin1, destinationA).then((values) => {
                return values
            })
            pushToRows(resources.data[i], dist_time_data)
        }
        // console.log(final_rows)

    } 

    function pushToRows(resources, dist_dur){
        resources["DISTANCE_MI"] = dist_dur[0];
        resources["ACTUAL_DUR_HR"] = dist_dur[1];
        resources["FINANCE_DUR_HR"] = (dist_dur[0] / 45.0).toFixed(2)
        final_rows.push(resources)   
    }
```

Comment: Note that `.then((values) => { return values; })` is totally pointless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're looking for `Promise.all`

Comment: @Bergi, great could you show me how to implement it in the context of this problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, it's just left over from numerous attempts at debugging, thanks

Comment: @RodSteele I know you've already tried for 3 hours, but did any of your approaches include `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you would need to do is just store promises in an array in the for loop and then wait for these promises to resolve using Promise.all but this would parallelize your requests to google distance api.

```
    function getDistTime(resources){
        const promiseArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < resources.data.length; i++) {
            var origin1 = $("#citystate").val();
            var destinationA = resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION CITY'] + ',' + resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION STATE'];
            promiseArr.push(googleRequest(origin1, destinationA));
            
        }
        // Not sure how would you use the data pushed in rows but since you are not waiting for promises to be resolved, data would be updated later on 
        return Promise.all(promiseArr)
            .then((resultsArr) => {
                resultsArr.forEach((result, i) => pushToRows(resources.data[i], result));
            })

    } 

    function pushToRows(resources, dist_dur){
        resources["DISTANCE_MI"] = dist_dur[0];
        resources["ACTUAL_DUR_HR"] = dist_dur[1];
        resources["FINANCE_DUR_HR"] = (dist_dur[0] / 45.0).toFixed(2)
        final_rows.push(resources)   
    }
```

I would recommend to use async-await which are syntactic sugar to promises but make your code easy to understand and remove the complications that come with promise chaining.

Comment: `i` is undefined in your `forEach` loop. You should not use `final_rows.push` at all, rather make a promise for the `resources` and have the `final_rows` as the result of the `Promise.all`

Comment: true. my bad. also, we could use index from forEach since ordering would be maintained to update

Comment: One could use the index from `forEach`, but one should not use `forEach` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you move your `pushToRows()` inside where you `return values`, you will have access to that data.

```
googleRequest(origin1, destinationA).then((values) => {
    pushToRows(resources.data[i], values);
});
```

Until that promise resolves, `dist_time_data` would be undefined

You could also convert to `Promise.all()` which takes an array of promises and resolves when all of the promises are complete:

```
function getDistTime(resources){
    const promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < resources.data.length; i++) {
        var origin1 = $("#citystate").val();
        var destinationA = resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION CITY'] + ',' + resources.data[i]['DEMOBILIZATION STATE'];
        promises.push(googleRequest(origin1, destinationA));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        return results.map((result, i) => {
            return {
                ...resources.data[i],
                DISTANCE_MI: result[0],
                ACTUAL_DUR_HR: result[1],
                FINANCE_DUR_HR: (result[0] / 45.0).toFixed(2)
            };
        });
    });
}

getDistTime(resources).then(result => {
    //result is now "final_rows"
});
```